# Setting-up c++ in visual studio code on mac

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I cannot find "Tasks: Add a default build task" from the command palette to set the compiler for c++. Is there any other way to set up the compiler to run c++ code in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1):

First, open you *.cpp* file on the editor pane. Then open the command palette (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>), then search for "*Tasks: Configure Default Build Task*":

[image]

Select that, then select the appropriate C++ compiler:

[image]

VS Code will then automatically create a _tasks.json* with the default task settings for compiling your code using the selected compiler. To run the created task, select the *.cpp* file configured in the task, then select *Terminal* > *Run Build Task..* (or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>).

More information on this is available from the VS Code documentation: [Clang on macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

Answer (score 0):

The Tasks related menu items are listed under the Menu `Terminal`, or can be accessed by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> and start to type `Tasks:`